# Building a blog like Stack Overflow - is it against copyright?

Tags: discussion, copyright

I don't know where to ask in relation to my doubts.

Today, I'm building a new blog for an online class and the appearance looks like this Stack Overflow site because I feel that Stack Overflow is nice and full of  features. But I don't mean to copy that fully. Here's my new blog> http://www.in-grammar.com/.

Please let me know if my work is against copyright or something. If it is wrong, I would reconstruct my blog.

Comment: It *seems* like you might have better luck [contacting the team](/contact), since this is really a legal question for Stack Exchange Inc., more than a question about the Stack Exchange network (a subtle difference, but an important one). You might get an answer here, but you'd be better off getting an undoubtedly official one. I *think* what you've done is generic enough so-as not to cause problems, but I'm in **absolutely no** position to speak on behalf of Stack Exchange's intellectual property holdings or claims.

Comment: If you want to be very helpful to whomever has to make the final call, you may want to amend to your post or contact form some details of what you're worried may be infringing on any property held by Stack Exchange. If your case is reviewed (by the team or otherwise), someone will undoubtedly go to your site and see some of what you're talking about, but if you're up-front about some of what you've used or been inspired by, that will probably make the whole process go more smoothly.

Comment: so sweet response mr @MatthewHaugen, thanks a lot. I don't mean to copy the flows system because I'm not an expert in building. thanks for the link, I will try to contact the team then.

Comment: No problem. I definitely applaud your "better safe than sorry" approach to this--many sites attempt to imitate or straight-up copy designs from [se] without a second thought, which is frustrating independently of whether they technically infringe. While you're at it, you should be made aware of [ell.se], which caters to what I believe is a similar audience as your site.

Comment: yes, I already know the site 'English Language Learners' :( ... I keep trying to contact. my blog now is just a concept and would go further if everything is in right way. thanks for your opinion, I'm trying to go fair in everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blog can't really be a clone of Q&A site.

Stack Exchange does not have a patent over the voting concept (upvotes and downvotes), or arrow icons in general. Any web site can use those freely.

Unless you copy whole CSS files, contents, or images from Stack Exchange into your website I think it's quite safe to say that you're not violating any copyright.

Comment: Since I don't know law of copyright, I'd prefer contacting team as suggested by @matthew haugen. However, I don't receive the response. Besides, copying identically would reduce my blog prestige. I would try to go with my own style but the same system (downvote,upvotes and solved). you know that I'm trying to find something safe from now on. And, it is impossible for me to copy whole files, contents or images and I'm sure I wouldn't do that.

Comment: The team get lots of requests, give them few days to respond to your email.

Comment: I just don't know where to ask about this stuff and marked as off-topic. it's okay, but the team really answered my question which is related to 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/
http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance
and finally, I decide to keep on running my blog since I don't find anything against clones issue, trademark and attribution. thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a whole list of [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones). If SE hasn't sued them, your blog really isn't a problem.

Anyways, the Q&A model isn't even unique to Stack Exchange. Ever hear of Yahoo Answers?

Comment: yahoo answer? not yet so far. This is about the system and site work concept, cloning does not mean both things. But I agree not to design in SE lists, if possible.

Comment: @Jean Gkol: Yahoo Answers has the (in)famous *[How Is Babby Formed?](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed)*. It is also an example of what not to do when it comes to Q&A sites.

Comment: lolz... but it inspires me to get more carefully and be fair in 'action' :D